# Photoshop: Animated PNG?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, png, cs5, plugin

Photoshop CS5 doesn't seem to natively support saving image as APNG even tho few of the major browsers already support it. Are there any export plugins or such available for Photoshop?

Comment: "Few major browsers" being currently Firefox, SeaMonkey and Opera. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG#Application_support

Comment: I may be wrong (someone correct me if I am) but I thought the APNG format was abandoned no too long ago.

Comment: @DA01 that'd be a shame. It's a great idea because it supports alpha and practically lossless animations without taking too much space. For small images, that is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**For 24-bit/32-bits APNG:**
In Photoshop (File - Export - Render Video), then use [apngasm](https://github.com/apngasm/apngasm/releases).
Checked method.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! After Aeons of waiting xD! Gotta check this out the first thing when I get home.

Comment: This is the way to go, but... the problem on my system is that it seems to take 'forever', for just 30 frames (granted, each frame is big!)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that to date there are none.

You could try to work this around by exporting each frame as a PNG in Photoshop and then use an external application to merge the PNGs to an APNG. See the [list of related software on animatedpng.com](http://animatedpng.com/index.php/software/). For example [Japng](http://www.reto-hoehener.ch/japng/) or [APNG Assembler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apngasm/) could do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, what would be the quickest and simplest way to do that? Let's say I'm dealing with 100 gifs that need to be APNG.

Comment: If the GIFs are already animated, probably the quickest way is to use gif2apng: http://gif2apng.sourceforge.net/ If the GIFs are supposed to be single frames in the APNG you should consult the software list I posted - or first convert the GIFs to PNGs and then convert the PNGs to APGNs with e.g. the aforementioned Japng or APNG Assembler.

Comment: Yes, but if the gifs need Photoshop attention, e.g., resizing (Photoshop resize is usually superb compared to conversion tools) and are already animated.

Comment: Well, *first* do the needed edits to GIFs, save as a GIF and *then* use mentioned tools to convert the GIF to APNG.

Comment: Oh yeah I know, I know. I was thinking if you had a quick way to offer for saving individual frames as separate files.

Comment: Probably some batch processing/scripting should be involved - but that would better serve as a new question :-)

Comment: Is there a way to create a cinemagarph based on APNG?

Answer (score 3):

[Photopea photo editor](https://www.Photopea.com) can open APNG (and GIF) and place each frame into a separate layer. Then, you can download it as a layered PSD.

It can also convert a layered PSD into APNG (or GIF), while placing each layer into a separate frame. You can find more details [here](https://blog.photopea.com/photopea-3-1-brings-aniamtions.html).

Photopea is basically "Anything to PSD" and "PSD to Anything".

** I am an author of Photopea and I would be very glad to get some feedback about this new feature :)

Comment: Awesome. I was able to open a APNG created by macOS Finder (exported a multipage PDF). Then extract one of those pages, which was I needed to do...

Comment: All right! Photopea rocks for sure (and, what do you know, it seems to be quite faster than Photoshop, at least on my (old) Mac. There is just an issue, though: I don't have 'one layer per frame'. Instead, I have _several_ layers (many of which redundant or transitional frames), of which a subset is composed together to provide the full animation. Photoshop keeps the animation timeline separate from the actual layers. So I'd need a tool that 'reads' the timeline and saves one layer per frame — and then Photopea would do the rest of the work!

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn if you want to make animations in Photopea using the "underscore mechanism", put all layers into a folder and give the folder the "underscore name".